# Difference on windows and linux webpage background?

Tags: html, css

I am making a website for my school, and I used to do that work on windows 7 before i switched to Ubuntu. I know that I used 1920x1080 resolution pictures for background on windows and it was perfect but on ubuntu it does not fit. I tried in a couple of different browsers. At school they are reviewing it on windows, my concern is if I make it lower resolution to fit here on my system will it mess up the website when they review it and vice versa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `background-size: cover;` property to your background image styles. From https://developer.mozilla.org quoting:

> The cover value specifies that the background image should be sized so that it is as small as possible while ensuring that both dimensions are greater than or equal to the corresponding size of the container.

It will not perfectly fit for some greater resolutions or resolutions with different ratios, but it will ensure that it covers it completely at the cost of fitting the whole image. The image will not get stretched either.